# algorithm2e with boxruled gives overfull hbox

Tags: boxes, warnings, algorithm2e

I am using the algorithm2e package with the boxruled option to format my pseudo-code. However, I am getting an overfull hbox, which I suspect is due to margin/box conflicts.

Does anyone have a fix for this? Minimal working example provided:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{llncs}

\usepackage[boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlFnt{\scriptsize}
\SetAlCapFnt{\scriptsize}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{input}
    \KwResult{output}
    a;
    b;
    c;
    \caption{lalala}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coding for the `boxruled` option produces a box that doesn't take into account the width of the rules.  This can be corrected as follows, by redefining one internal command:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlFnt{\scriptsize}
\SetAlCapFnt{\scriptsize}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\scriptsize}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@caption@boxruled}{%
  \hrule
  \hbox to \hsize{%
    \vrule\hskip-0.4pt
    \vbox{   
       \vskip\interspacetitleboxruled%
       \unhbox\algocf@capbox\hfill
       \vskip\interspacetitleboxruled
       }%
     \hskip-0.4pt\vrule%
   }\nointerlineskip%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{input}
    \KwResult{output}
    a;
    b;
    c;
    \caption{lalala}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The newcommand differs from that in the style file by (a) printing the horizontal rule first and (b) hiding the widths (`0.4pt`) of the vertical rules.  This essentially how `\framebox` works, which is what is used for boxing up the body of the algorithm.  It can't be used on the caption as one doesn't want to double the dividing rule.

Comment: Are you a friend of Marcel Proust? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as mentioned in the question, but the answer given by Andrew did not work on a mch larger document I had. 
Maybe I had other packages in my preamble that prevented the idea Andrew had. 
It will take me a few days just to figure out which package caused it,
but in the mean time I can give a easier solution that help me when I had a problems with margins and my old printer.

Just after loading the document class, article in my case I needed to 
improved the margins of my document since the printer was always off by a bit.
[The single command of `\usepackage[4apaper]{geometry)`
was not doing it by itself.]
I added some corrections and it did help erase the issue of 
`Overfull \hbox (17.0pt too wide) detected at line' 
at the end of my algorithm call.

The snippet is only to offset the margins enough for my printer to work.

```
\hoffset -0.0625in 
\voffset 0.15625in
\parindent0em
```

If I find which package cause Andrew's answer not to work, I will come back here and add it as a comment.